# Good reference for partitions of unity?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, manifolds, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading about Sobolev Spaces and regularity theory of PDEs. The partition of unity lemma, as stated in Haim Brezis' *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, is as follows:

> Given $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a compact set and $U_0,U_1,...,U_k$ an open covering $C$ (i.e $C \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^{k}U_i$),  there exist $k+1$ functions $\theta_0,...,\theta_k \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that:
>
> 1. $0 \leq \theta_i(x) \leq 1 \quad \forall i=0,1,...,k$.
>
>    2. $\sum_{i=0}^k\theta_i(x)=1 $.
>    3. $sop(\theta_i) \subset U_i  \quad \forall i =1,2,...,k$.
>    4. $sop(\theta_0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n-C$.
>
> If $C$ is the boundary of an open set $\Omega$, then $\theta_{0 |\Omega} \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Could you please provide me some good reference in which I can read the proof of this result?

Comment: Brezis suggests four (four!) books as reference. Don't you like them?

Comment: @Siminore Obviously not. I want to cite in a paper I am making a book where this is stated straightforward and shown without too much complication.

Comment: What is wrong the the proofs in those books?